# How to preview PDF file on Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

i need help. I tried to upload pdf file then the preview of the uploaded file will be shown on the pane. Right now, i'm using javafx and fxml. Any idea of how to do it?
Below is my interface. [image]

the idea is, after i upload the pdf file, then on the left pane, the pdf file will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways i can think of

Using jpedal library (it has a free version that works for preview) https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/

or you can add a javafx webview and display it using javascript library https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: jpedal is not free ,btw